# Кодировка properties в Apache Camel

Tags: кодировка, properties, camel, blueprint

Есть необходимость использовать русские символы в .properties. Согласно документации Camel считывает атрибуты в формате ISO-8859-1. Есть ли способ изменить эту кодировку на UTF-8?

Я использую Camel в связке с Blueprint контейнером:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.2.0"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.2.0 ">

    <ext:property-placeholder id="limit-processor">
        <ext:default-properties>
            <ext:property name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        </ext:default-properties>
        <ext:location>file:etc/ActiveMQConnection.properties</ext:location>
        <ext:location>file:etc/automation/somth.properties</ext:location>
    </ext:property-placeholder>
```

Вышеописанный способ не работает

Answer (score 0):

Получилось найти решение.
В ext:property-placeholder нет атрибута encoding, поэтому он по умолчанию всегда считывает в ISO-8859-1.
Нужно было убрать из него файлы properties, в которых есть кириллица, и перенести в Camel'овский propertyPlaceholder:

```
 <ext:property-placeholder id="limit-processor">
        <ext:location>file:etc/ActiveMQConnection.properties</ext:location>
    </ext:property-placeholder>
---------------------------------

<camelContext id="proc_tvh_limit" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" messageHistory="true">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties"  location="file:etc/automation/somth.properties" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <!-- route -->
        <routeBuilder ref="Router"/>

    </camelContext>
```